# How to Center Rotated text with CSS

Tags: css, rotation, transform, centering

I'm trying to write a bar with rotated tabs. Rotation is done with `transform:rotate`. The problem: `width:100%` is computed *before* rotation, so it will actually be set to 100% of the height of the rotated tab.

```
.tab-caption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;  /* width before rotation! */
    top: 50%;
    height: 2px;  /* actual text will overlap! */
    margin-top: -1px;  /* subtract half the height */
    line-height: 0px;  /* centre the text on the base line */
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Vertical centring works correctly even if the text overlaps the div. For horizontal centring, this trick doesn't work; the text would always start at the left even though `text-align:center` was specified.

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/digorydoo/pzvuntd4/

In the fiddle, everything works fine for short captions, because the height that becomes the width after rotation is shorter than the caption. For long captions, centring is not done correctly. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's very simple:

```
.tab-caption {
    position: absolute;
    /* width: 100%; */ /* (remove this) width before rotation! */
    top: 50%;
    height: 2px;  /* actual text will overlap! */
    margin-top: -1px;  /* subtract half the height */
    line-height: 0px;  /* centre the text on the base line */
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%; /* added */
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(90deg); /* added translateX */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/pzvuntd4/2/

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that translateX works with percentages! Thanks!